# Add columns in a pandas dataframe to a list

Tags: list, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
Latitude    Longiutde
53.553      -80.3123
58.1211     -81.3245
```

I am trying to convert this dataframe to a list of lists to use it in my plotting package.

```
[[53.553, -80.3123], [58.1211, -81.3245]]
```

I tried with iterating through the pandas rows to append these columns to a list but for some reason I am not even able to make my first level list.

```
list.append(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `tolist` method on the underlying numpy array

```
df
```

[image]

```
df.values.tolist()

[[53.553000000000004, -80.3123], [58.1211, -81.3245]]
```